# Auto sizing div

Tags: html, css

On most of my sites, I put information into a div that has rounded corners with a fox shadow.  I was wondering if there is a way to have this parent div automatically center itself vertically & horizontally while changing its height & width based on its children.  Below is as close as I have gotten but the div stays to the upper left of my page.  It seems to fit the content well but the position is not close to where I'd want it.

```
.appRoundedShadow {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px outset gray;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

I haven't been successful with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flexbox should be the solution for your problem, read more about CSS flexbox [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.appRoundedShadow {
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
width: auto;
background-color: white;
padding: 25px;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 1px outset gray;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="appRoundedShadow">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you moving a new container tag instead of the stylized tag ? Also, `width:100%` is the default value

Comment: Just explaining the idea

Answer (score 2):

Using flex is easy. The think you must not forget is: 
The child is vertically centered on the parent **height**. So you must set a minimum to works or height of parent is equal to child height (and no top/bottom margin are required to center it)

```css
/* Normalize */
html, body { 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%; 
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.appRoundedShadow {
  margin:auto;

  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px outset gray;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="appRoundedShadow"></div>
```